# NHibernate Creating Randomly Id

Tags: winforms, sqlite, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-xml-mapping

I have 2 Classes and 2 Mapping Itens, when I CreatingSchema my NHibernate is creating a Randomly ID Foreign Key on my SQLite database, I dont have 'ID' on my code, I dont know where it is coming from.

1. Class

   ```
   public class Locacoes{
   public Locacoes()
   {

   }
   public virtual int Codigo { get; set; }

   public virtual string Data { get; set; }

   public virtual string DataFesta { get; set; }

   public virtual string HoraInicio { get; set; }

   public virtual string HoraFim { get; set; }

   public virtual int TipoEspaco { get; set; }

   public virtual string NomeCelebrante { get; set; }

   public virtual string Cep { get; set; }

   public virtual string Endereco { get; set; }

   public virtual string Complemento { get; set; }

   public virtual string Bairro { get; set; }

   public virtual string Cidade { get; set; }

   public virtual string Uf { get; set; }

   public virtual string Fone { get; set; }

   public virtual string Obs { get; set; }

   public virtual double Desconto { get; set; }

   public virtual double ValorTotal { get; set; }

   public virtual TemaFesta CodTemaFesta { get; set; }

   }
   }
   ```

2.Class

```
public class TemaFesta
{
    public TemaFesta()
    {

    }
    public virtual int Codigo { get; set; }
    public virtual string Descricao { get; set; }

    public virtual ISet<Locacoes> Locacoes { get; set; }
}
}
```

Sorry. I cant post my Mapping Codes herem SO is not showing it, so i post pics
1. Mapping
[Fist Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kZ6G.png)
2. Mapping
[Mapping2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oeoa.png)

and then, my SQlite creating statement

```
CREATE TABLE Locacoes (Codigo  integer primary key autoincrement, Data TEXT,      DataFesta TEXT, HoraInicio TEXT, HoraFim TEXT, TipoEspaco INT, NomeCelebrante     TEXT, Cep TEXT, Endereco TEXT, Complemento TEXT, Bairro TEXT, Cidade TEXT, Uf TEXT, Fone TEXT, Obs TEXT, Desconto DOUBLE, ValorTotal DOUBLE, CodTemaFesta INT, id INT, constraint FK1C57939D5747171D foreign key (CodTemaFesta) references TemaFesta, constraint CodTemaFesta foreign key (id) references TemaFesta)
```

"constraint CodTemaFesta foreign key (id) references TemaFesta)" 
I dont have it, so why is nhibernate creating it?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing random going on here.

The problem is the "set" mapping.

You are declaring a foreign-key="CodTemaFesta" which is then getting generated with your CreateSchema statement.  I'm not sure it you want to create this db foreign key, but that's what you declared.

If you just are mapping this in code you need to give it a column name like this

```
<key column="<column-name>" />
```